# Replace NA with mode from categorical dataset R

Tags: r, missing-data, categorical-data

I have a dataset with `categorical` and `NA` observations of 10 variables. I want to replace the `NA` values of each column with the mode. I did a histogram of each variable for identifying the density for each observation and got the mode. I know what values to replace the `NA`s in each column with.

I saw there was a related post, but I already know what values to replace. Here's the link: [Replace mean or mode for missing values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731192/replace-mean-or-mode-for-missing-values-in-r)

Here's to reproduce the dataset:

```
> #Create data with missing values
> set.seed(1)
> dat <- data.frame(x=sample(letters[1:3],20,TRUE), y=rnorm(20), 
                                                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> dat[c(5,10,15),1] <- NA
```

Here's an example:

```
> #The head of the first five observations
> head(SmallStoredf, n=5)

    Age Gender HouseholdIncome MaritalStatus PresenceofChildren HomeOwnerStatus HomeMarketValue
1  <NA>   Male            <NA>          <NA>               <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
2 45-54 Female            <NA>          <NA>               <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
5 45-54 Female        75k-100k       Married                Yes             Own       150k-200k
6 25-34   Male        75k-100k       Married                 No             Own       300k-350k
7 35-44 Female       125k-150k       Married                Yes             Own       250k-300k
  Occupation             Education LengthofResidence
1       <NA>                  <NA>              <NA>
2       <NA>                  <NA>              <NA>
5       <NA> Completed High School           9 Years
6       <NA> Completed High School       11-15 years
7       <NA> Completed High School           2 Years
```

In this example, I want `NA`s in `HomeOwnerStatus` replaced with `Own`, `HomeMarketValue` with `350K-500K`, and `Occupation` with `Professional`.

**EDIT:** I tried inputting the values in, but got an error about three of the columns.

```
> replacementVals <- c(Age = "45-54", Gender = "Male", HouseholdIncome = "50K-75K", 
+                      MaritalStatus = "Single", PresenceofChildren = "No",
+                      HomeOwnerStatus = "Own", HomeMarketValue = "350K-500K",
+                      Occupation = "Professional", Education = "Completed High School",
+                      LengthofResidence = "11-15yrs")
> indx1 <- replacementVals[col(df2)][is.na(df2[,names(replacementVals)])]
> df2[is.na(df2[,names(replacementVals)])]  <- indx1
#Warning messages:
#1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = c("50K-75K", "50K-75K",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
#2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = c("350K-500K", "350K-500K",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
#3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = c("11-15yrs", "11-15yrs",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Here's the output:

```
> head(SmallStoredf)

    Age Gender HouseholdIncome MaritalStatus PresenceofChildren HomeOwnerStatus HomeMarketValue
1 45-54   Male            <NA>        Single                 No             Own            <NA>
2 45-54 Female            <NA>        Single                 No             Own            <NA>
5 45-54 Female        75k-100k       Married                Yes             Own       150k-200k
6 25-34   Male        75k-100k       Married                 No             Own       300k-350k
7 35-44 Female       125k-150k       Married                Yes             Own       250k-300k
8 55-64   Male        75k-100k       Married                 No             Own       150k-200k
    Occupation             Education LengthofResidence
1 Professional Completed High School              <NA>
2 Professional Completed High School              <NA>
5 Professional Completed High School           9 Years
6 Professional Completed High School       11-15 years
7 Professional Completed High School           2 Years
8 Professional Completed High School       16-19 years
```

Only `NA` values in some columns were replaced.

Comment: How do you want the replacement selected when two categories in a variable have the same max count?

Comment: @Scott Davis I guess you need to change `factor` class to `character` class.  It is best to read the files with the option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. I was able to replicate your error when the columns are factor.  So, change it to `character` columns.`SmallStoredf[] <- lapply(SmallStoredf, as.character)` if you have already read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I amended your reproducible example a little bit, here's the setup

```
> #Create data with missing values
> set.seed(1)
> dat <- data.frame(x=sample(letters[1:3],20,TRUE), y=rnorm(20), 
                                              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> dat[c(5,10,15),1] <- NA
> dat[6,1]<-NA

#output
#     x                        y
#1     a  1.511781168450847978590
#2     b  0.389843236411431093291
#3     b -0.621240580541803755210
#4     c -2.214699887177499881830
#5  <NA>  1.124930918143108193874
#6     c                       NA
#7     c -0.016190263098946087311
#8     b  0.943836210685299215051
#9     b  0.821221195098088552200
#10 <NA>  0.593901321217508826322
#11    a  0.918977371608218240873
#12    a  0.782136300731067102276
#13    c  0.074564983365190601328
#14    b -1.989351695863372793127
#15 <NA>  0.619825747894710232799
#16    b -0.056128739529000784558
#17    c -0.155795506705329295238
#18    c -1.470752383899274429169
#19    b -0.478150055108620353206
#20    c  0.417941560199702411005
```

now define your replacement vals, labeled by the columns you want to have NAs replaced

```
replacementVals<-c(x="Xreplace", y="Yreplace")
```

and the next call can replace them in all in one shot

```
dat[is.na(dat[,names(replacementVals)])]<-replacementVals

#          x                   y
#1         a    1.51178116845085
#2         b   0.389843236411431
#3         b  -0.621240580541804
#4         c    -2.2146998871775
#5  Xreplace    1.12493091814311
#6         c            Yreplace
#7         c -0.0161902630989461
#8         b   0.943836210685299
#9         b   0.821221195098089
#10 Yreplace   0.593901321217509
#11        a   0.918977371608218
#12        a   0.782136300731067
#13        c  0.0745649833651906
#14        b   -1.98935169586337
#15 Xreplace    0.61982574789471
#16        b -0.0561287395290008
#17        c  -0.155795506705329
#18        c   -1.47075238389927
#19        b   -0.47815005510862
#20        c   0.417941560199702
```

But as akrun pointed out, and subsequently solved, this didn't map well to your second data frame example.  This is just taken straight from the comments they made (so either way they should probably get the check on this question)

We'll do the setup, I'm not going to do all the prints except for the result

```
HomeOwnerStatus = c(NA,NA,NA ,"Rent", "Rent" ) 
HomeMarketValue = c(NA,NA,NA, "350k", "350k") 
Occupation = c(NA,NA,NA, NA, NA) 
SmallStoreddf<-data.frame(HomeOwnerStatus,HomeMarketValue,Occupation, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

replacementVals<-c("HomeOwnerStatus" = "Rent", "HomeMarketValue"="350k", "Occupation"="Professional")
```

Then in two steps (which could be combined into one really long line) you go

```
#get the values that we will be replacing
indx1<-replacementVals[col(SmallStoreddf)][is.na(SmallStoreddf[, names(replacementVals)])]

#do the replacement
SmallStoreddf[is.na(SmallStoredf[,names(replacementVals)])] <-indx1

#  HomeOwnerStatus HomeMarketValue   Occupation
#1             Own            350k Professional
#2             Own            350k Professional
#3             Own            350k Professional
#4            Rent            350k Professional
#5            Rent            350k Professional
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing as akrun, I was typing it up when they posted.

Comment: It is a bit different and I liked it.  So, you can leave it to the OP for making the decision.  But, perhaps the length should be checked for the `replacementVals`

Comment: I tried this `replacementVals <- c(HomeOwnerStatus="Own", HomeMarketValue="350K-500K", Occupation="Professional"); SmallStoredf[is.na(SmallStoredf[,names(replacementVals)])]  <- replacementVals# Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(SmallStoredf[, names(replacementVals)])`  May be I made some typo.

Comment: This worked `indx1 <- replacementVals[col(SmallStoredf)][is.na(SmallStoredf[,names(replacementVals)])]; SmallStoredf[is.na(SmallStoredf[,names(replacementVals)])]  <- indx1`  It may be possible to tweak/shorten the code.

Comment: yes good call, it seems with the quick write up I didn't handle the dimensions, I'll need to amend the answer

Comment: @akrun on your second edit, I don't know where to put in the variables and replacement values. Should I replace `names` with the variable and `replacementVals` with the number/letter?

Comment: @Scott Davis the `replacementVals` are the same if I understand your question. `replacementVals <- c(HomeOwnerStatus="Own", HomeMarketValue="350K-500K", Occupation="Professional")`

Comment: @akrun, it worked except for in three columns. I'll repost the columns with all the results. I posted only three last time.

Comment: @Scott Davis It might have to do with the subsetting.

Comment: @ScottDavis if you could post the code to create the dataframe you show in your new edit, that'd help a lot, because as of right now we're just kind of spitballing on what exactly it is(as it seems you use factors given the error messages, and above I use strings).

Comment: @DMT I just solved the error. I didn't input the right factor values, for example lower case "k" in 50k-75k and 350k-500k as well as "years" in 11-15 years.

Comment: @ScottDavis great glad to hear it

Answer (score 1):

Try: (Using your second example as it was a bit unclear when you showed two datasets)

```
indx <- which(is.na(SmallStoredf), arr.ind=TRUE)
SmallStoredf[indx] <- c("Own", "350K-500K", "Professional")[indx[,2]]
SmallStoredf
#  HomeOwnerStatus HomeMarketValue   Occupation
#1             Own       350K-500K Professional
#2             Own       350K-500K Professional
#3             Own       350K-500K Professional
#4            Rent       350k-500k Professional
#5            Rent        500k-1mm Professional
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading comment.

If you are wanting to replace the missing data with the most frequent category, there may be an equal count of categories within a variable. So in the code below, the replacements are randomly sampled from the categories that are most frequent.

```
# some example data with missing
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(letters[1:3],20,TRUE), 
                  y=sample(letters[1:3],20,TRUE),
                  w=rnorm(20),
                  z=sample(letters[1:3],20,TRUE),                  
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat[c(5,10,15),1] <- NA
dat[c(3,7),2] <- NA

# function to get replacement for missing
# sample is used to randomly select categories, allowing for the case 
# when the maximum frequency is shared by more than one category 

f <- function(x) {
                tab <- table(x)
                l <- sum(is.na(x))
                sample(names(tab)[tab==max(tab)], l, TRUE)
                }

# as we are using sample, set.seed before replacing
set.seed(1)

for(i in 1:ncol(dat)){
            if(!is.numeric(dat[i]))
                  dat[i][is.na(dat[i])] <- f(dat[i])
            }
```

*gentle warning*: you should think carefully before imputing missing data this way. For example, income is often more likely to be missing for highest and lowest categories. By this method you may be imputing an average wage incorrectly. You should consider why each variable is missing and if it is reasonable to assume the data is MCAR or MAR. If so, i would then consider a more robust method of imputation (`mice` package).